# Capture groups of comma separate digits and floating point values enclosed in parentheses

Tags: php, regex

The goal is to capture 3 groups of values separated by commas enclosed in parentheses.

The string to be parsed:-

`(8x10x2cm, 0.2kg, 596010 SKU)`

At a minimum, there would be 3 named capture groups `dimensions`, `weight` and `sku`

The specified unit `cm` and `kg` and keyword `SKU` does not need to be considered and should not be captured.

Ideally the `dimesion` capture group would split on `x` to give additional named capture groups `width`, `height` and `depth`

Floating point values such as `0.2` in `weight` also needs to be considered in `dimensions` e.g. `8.5x10.5x2cm` for capture

`width` = 8
`height` = 10
`depth` = 2
`weight` = 0.2
`sku` = 596010

Note `sku` is not always numeric but always appears before the string `SKU` e.g. possible `sku` values include `C798015`, `596001B`, `572920B10`, `741150.1`

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex:

```
\((?<width>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(?<height>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(?<depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)cm,\s*(?<weight>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)kg,\s*(?<sku>.*)\s*SKU\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrW3JS/1) which matches all your sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `preg_match_all` followed by flattening the output 2D array:

```php
$input = "(8x10x2cm, 0.2kg, 596010 SKU)";
preg_match_all("/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)cm, (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)kg, (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: SKU)?\)/", $input, $matches);
$output = [];
for ($i=1; $i < count($matches); $i++){
    $output[$i - 1] = $matches[$i][0];
}

print_r($output);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 0.2
    [4] => 596010
)
```

I didn't name the capture groups, but then again you don't need that to make use of the above answer, as the order of capture groups is guaranteed by the regex pattern being used.